# I can not access Google Plus with Firefox and Chrome/Chromium but I can with Midori/Epiphany, how can I solve it?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, midori, epiphany, google-plus

I'm having this weird issue where I can access G+ only with Epiphany and Midori. With Firefox and Chrome/Chromium I have several problems opening the page, and when it opens doesn't work properly.

¿Any idea of what can it be or how to solve it?

Comment: Have you cleaned the cache in those browsers?

Comment: Yes, both from the browsers and with BleachBit

Comment: Have you tried with all your Firefox/Chrome/Chromium extensions disabled? Are you using some javascript blockers?

Comment: I don't have any extension installed apart from the desktop integration ones.